# Query two tabels with PK FK relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, select

I have two table. Table A and Table B. They have some common columns . I want a joint result using inner joint on this column. The problem is they don't have any PK Fk relationship.

Is is possible in Hibernate or for Hibernate, relationship is Mandatory? If this is possible how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

HQL: `select a,b from A a,B b where a.prop = b.prop`

Note that this will result in a cross join and will return an array of objects (`Object[]`)

Comment: Since i am providing constrain on which to join won't this be an inner join?

Comment: what about the configuration . should I mention anything special in it.

Comment: No, hibernate will generate cross joins when you don't have foreign keys and needs no special configuration.

Comment: How in what way will i get the two results. I mean if there is two entity class then hibernate will return list of only one. how will i get the other one.

Comment: Because of `select a,b` you will get a list which each element is an array of two objects. First one is of type `A` second one of type `B`.

Comment: What configuration is need so that the result will consist of list of object A and the each object A will have attribute B b which will relate to that object B.

Comment: What you are talking about is a custom query result. Have a look at `Hibernate Transformers` to learn how to get custom objects.
If you need to get `A` object as the result, you will need to put a property of `B` inside it and mark it as `@Transient`.